# Are there situations when you don't get point by answering a question?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I answered [Jqgrid search toolbar filter unique drop lists with Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881382/jqgrid-search-toolbar-filter-unique-drop-lists-with-json) on Stack Overflow 12 hours ago, which was accepted 2 hours later. In this case I didn't get additional points rewarded.

Are there situations where you don't get points by answering a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

Your answer was flagged community wiki, and community wiki posts do not gain any reputation.

You can find out more in the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)